# Which is the max value of the determinant with 4 lines and 4 colums ,where every term is +- 1?

Tags: determinant

I understand that this problem can be solve with the volume of a tetrahedron.

But i don't know how.

please help me !

\begin{vmatrix}
\pm1 & \pm1 & \pm1 & \pm1 \\ 
\pm1 & \pm1 & \pm1 & \pm1 \\ 
\pm1 & \pm1 & \pm1 & \pm1 \\ 
\pm1 & \pm1 & \pm1 & \pm1  \notag
\end{vmatrix}

Comment: The maximal value is $16$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy $16$ quite obviously *is* an upper bound, I am curious is the absolute upper bound though? I mean can it be achieved?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy you will notice I am not the OP, but I get your point. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have $|\det[x_1 \cdots x_n ] | \le \|x_1\|\cdots \|x_n\|$ (Hadamard inequality).

This shows the determinant is upper bounded by 16.

Now choose
$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, and compute $\det A = 16$.

Comment: Are you saying $16$? In that case can it be achieved?

Comment: @Sabyasachi: My typing skills are limited. Yes, it can be achieved...

Comment: Ah very nice. +1. It is very satisfying when the first obvious trivial upperbound is the actual upper bound.